# What does 14px/26px font size in css do?

Tags: css

I've been inspecting someone elses CSS and I noticed they are doing something I haven't seen before...

```
body {font:14px/26px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif}
```

What does the 14px/26px do? I've tried to google it but nothing seems to come up.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I have inherited a lot of CSS and never come across this before, or written it myself. Learn something new every day, I guess.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the CSS 2.1 Specifications for the `font` shorthand property:

> 15.8 Shorthand font property: the 'font' property
>
> 'font'
> Value:    [ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]? <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit

The first value is the `font-size` value, and the second value is the `line-height` value.

So `font: 14px/26px ...` means:

```
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 26px;
font-family: ...
```

Comment: ahhh, so simple.. I thought it might of been 14 divided by 26 for some weird reason.